# Css, wrapping two divs either side of center div

Tags: html, css

I have the following jsfiddle, where i want the arrows to be either side of the center box. I have tried changing the position of the and floating but this does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/p4LES/1/

```
.holder {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.holder a {
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: #333;
}
.holder a:hover {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
}
.holder a.jp-current, a.jp-current:hover {
    color: #FF4242;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
    background: none;
}
.holder span {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Above is my CSS rules for the div in question. My question is how can i get the two arrows on the jsfiddle to appear either side of the 'ul' element?

Comment: What I see in your jsFiddle already looks like what you are describing to me. Can you post a pic of what you had in mind?

Comment: You could reduce the top value in the '.arrowPrev, .arrowNext' class definition (say to top: 5px;). See http://jsfiddle.net/p4LES/2/ .

Comment: @Jim Thanks! that worked. if you post an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @user667430: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the CSS and reduce the top value inthe '.arrowPrev, .arrowNext' class definition. For example, set top: 5px.

```
.arrowPrev, .arrowNext {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4LES/2/)